# Who Are The Guilty Parties? #2

Tags: logical-deduction

You've barely got back from [the island where your last case was](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24341/who-are-the-guilty-parties-1), when you hear that you are needed again:

> There is a group of people at an isolated villa.  In a curious twist, the aristocrats have all been murdered.  You have been sent to collect statements from each person.
>    - Each person in the group is either guilty or innocent.
>    - Each person is either friends or not friends with each other person.  The friendship is mutual.
>    - Each guilty person is friends with every other guilty person.
>    - Each innocent person has witnessed a number of events, which allows them to deduce the innocence or guilt of a number of people in the group.  This may or may not have been reciprocated.
>    - The guilty people know who the guilty and innocent parties are.
>    - Each person is either boastful or modest (to be explained below).
>
> The statements that each person makes are as follows:
>    - Innocent modest people will simply make a list of truthful statements.
>    - Innocent boastful people will do the same, but will also make a statement about a random other person about whom they know nothing.  If the person is their friend, they will say s/he is innocent.  Otherwise they'll just say something (innocent or guilty at random).
>    - Guilty modest people will say that friends are innocent (regardless of whether they are); they will say that non-friends are guilty (which is inaccurate, because their non-friends are innocent by the above definitions).
>    - Guilty boastful people will do the same.  But they will also make one truthful statement (either that one of their guilty friends is guilty or that one of their innocent non-friends is innocent).
>
> This situation seems all too common these days...

On this particular day, you go out to the island and get to sit down with the main characters:
**Elton, Roxann, Lamar, Laine, Diego, Marylee, Mika, Mendy, Tracey, and Ruth**

This is what you're able to glean from each one:

> **Statements of Elton:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Mika is guilty
>    - Lamar is innocent
>    - Laine is innocent
>
> **Statements of Roxann:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Elton is innocent
>    - Laine is innocent
>    - Lamar is guilty
>    - Mika is guilty
>    - Tracey is innocent
>    - Diego is innocent
>
> **Statements of Lamar:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Laine is innocent
>    - Mika is innocent
>    - Roxann is guilty
>    - Tracey is guilty
>
> **Statements of Laine:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Mika is guilty
>    - Mendy is guilty
>    - Tracey is innocent
>
> **Statements of Diego:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Elton is guilty
>    - Ruth is innocent
>    - Lamar is guilty
>    - Roxann is innocent
>
> **Statements of Marylee:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Mika is innocent
>    - Elton is guilty
>    - Laine is innocent
>
> **Statements of Mika:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Marylee is innocent
>    - Roxann is guilty
>    - Diego is innocent
>    - Laine is innocent
>    - Tracey is guilty
>
> **Statements of Mendy:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Laine is guilty
>    - Roxann is innocent
>    - Diego is innocent
>    - Lamar is innocent
>    - Mika is guilty
>
> **Statements of Tracey:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Laine is innocent
>    - Mika is guilty
>    - Elton is innocent
>
> **Statements of Ruth:**
>    - I am innocent
>    - Mika is innocent
>    - Elton is innocent
>    - Laine is innocent

It seems like a hopeless case, but then you remember occam's razor.  The simplest solution is likely to be it, in this case, the solution with the fewest number of co-conspirators is likely to be the answer.

Who murdered the aristocrats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer:**

> **Lamar, Mika, Mendy, and Marylee murdered them.**
>
>   Also, if we'd rather not use "Occam's Razor" as our evidence in court, we can comfortably arrest Lamar, Mika, and Mendy, while letting Roxann and Laine go (as these are consistent across all six possible solutions).

Logic:

> Let's start with a statement of "facts":
>
>  Name - Innocent (Not Innocent)
>
>  Elton – Lamar, Laine (Mika)
>  Roxann – Elton, Laine, Tracey, Diego (Lamar, Mika)
>  Lamar – Laine, Mika (Roxann, Tracey)
>  Laine – Tracey, (Mika, Mendy)
>  Diego – Ruth, Roxann (Elton, Lamar)
>  Marylee – Mika, Laine (Elton)
>  Mika – Marylee, Diego, Laine (Roxann, Tracey)
>  Mendy – Roxann, Diego, Lamar (Laine, Mika)
>  Tracey – Elton, Laine (Mika)
>  Ruth – Mika, Elton, Laine
>
>  So let's try to pair them into two groups, where "innocent" means same group and "guilty" means other group.
>
>  **Assumption: Roxann and Tracey are in opposite groups.**
>
>  In this case, both Lamar and Mika are boastful, with this as their only boast (either they are claiming an innocent or a friend guilty, depending on whether they're innocent or guilty). As a result, Mika must be friends with Laine (if Mika is guilty) or Laine must be innocent (if Mika is innocent).  Therefor, when Laine says Mika is guilty, that must be his boast (either they're both innocent, or they're both friends).  Therefor, Mendy must be in the other group from Laine.
>
>  Group 1: Mendy
>
>  Group 2: Laine
>
>  If Mika was innocent, then Marylee, Diego, and Laine must be innocent (because Roxann or Tracey is a boast), which means Laine's claim that Mika is guilty is a boast, so Tracey is innocent, which means her claims about Mika are a boast, so Elton is innocent, which means *his* claim about Mika is also a boast, so Lamar is innocent.  But then Diego is innocent and wrong about both Elton and Lamar.  Thus, our original guess was wrong, and Mika is guilty.
>
>  Group 1: Mendy
>
>  Group 2: Laine
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika
>
>  If Roxann was guilty, then Mika must be her boast, so Lamar is truly innocent.  Tracey would also be innocent, since she's in the other group from Roxann.  But then Lamar is boasting twice - he's wrong about both Mika and Tracey.  This can't be, so Roxann is innocent.
>
>  Since Roxann is innocent, Tracey must be Guilty (and a boast), so Elton, Laine, and Diego are innocent and Lamar must be guilty (and Mendy, being in the other group from Laine, must be guilty).  Diego is wrong about Elton, so that must be his boast, and Ruth is innocent.  Marylee is wrong about both Mika and Elton, so Marylee must be guilty.
>
>  ---
>
>  Possible Solution 1:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Elton, Laine, Diego, Ruth
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Tracey, Lamar, Marylee, Mendy
>
>  ---
>
>  **Alternative: Roxann and Tracey are in the same group**
>
>  Group 1: Roxann, Tracey
>
>  Neither Mika or Lamar can be in their group, because both of them claim they're both guilty.  For innocent or guilty, that would be two boasts.  Since we only have two total groups, Mika and Lamar are together.
>
>  Group 1: Roxann, Tracey
>
>  Group 2: Mika, Lamar
>
>  **Assumption: Laine and Mika are in the same group**
>
>  This means Laine is with Mika and Lamar
>
>  Mendy says Laine and Mika are both guilty, so Mendy is not in their group (otherwise, that would be two boasts).
>
>  Group 1: Roxann, Tracey, Mendy
>
>  Group 2: Mika, Lamar, Laine
>
>  But now Laine says that Tracey is innocent and Mika is guilty.  if Laine is innocent, then these are both boasts based on who shares a group.  Thus, Laine must be guilty, and friends with Tracey (where Mika is still a boast).
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Mendy
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Laine
>
>  But Roxann is innocent and said Laine was innocent - that's a boast, so Elton is innocent.  But then Elton says Lamar and Laine are innocent, which are both boasts!  This is inconsistent, so our assumption was false.
>
>  **Conclusion: Laine and Mika are in different groups**
>
>  Group 1: Roxann, Tracey, Laine
>
>  Group 2: Mika, Lamar
>
>  **Assumption: Mika is innocent**
>
>  This means we have:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Mika, Lamar
>
>  Guilty:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine
>
>  Mika is innocent and says that Laine is innocent, so that must be her only boast.  As a result, Marylee and Diego are innocent.
>
>  Innocent:
>  Mika, Lamar, Marylee, Diego
>
>  Guilty:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine
>
>  But then Diego is innocent, but claims Roxann is innocent and Lamar is guilty - these are both boasts, which is inconsistent. Thus, our assumption was false.
>
>  **Conclusion: Mika is guilty**
>
>  Now we have:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar
>
>  If Mendy were innocent, claiming Lamar innocent and Laine guilty would be two boasts, so Mendy is guilty.
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy
>
>  At this point, we've used all of Laine's statements, so we can stop worrying about him.
>
>  **Assumption: Diego and Elton are in the same group**
>
>  In this case, Diego must be boasting when he says Elton is guilty, so Lamar can't be a boast, which means Diego (and Elton) are innocent.  Also, Diego's claim about Ruth can't be a boast, so she's innocent.
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine, Diego, Elton, Ruth
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy
>
>  If Marylee were innocent, her claims about Mika and Elton would be boasts, so Marylee is guilty.
>
>  ---
>
>  Possible Solution 2:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine, Diego, Elton, Ruth
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy, Marylee
>
>  ---
>
>  This means Ruth is boasting about Mika, Tracey is consistent, Mendy is friends with Roxann and Diego and boasting about Mika, Mika is friends with Deigo or Laine or both, Marylee might be friends with Laine, Diego is boasting about Elton, Lamar might be friends with Laine, Roxann is consistent, and Elton is boasting about Lamar.  Everybody's statements line up, so this is a *possible* solution.
>
>  **Alternative: Diego and Elton are in different groups**
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy
>
>  in this case, Roxann has no useful knowledge to add (we know she boasted, but not about whom).  Tracey may or may not be boasting, but we don't gain any knowledge from her.
>
>  **Assumption: Ruth is Innocent**
>
>  In this case, Mika is a boast, so Elton is innocent, thus Diego is Guilty.  Marylee can't be innocent because then Mika and Elton would be boasts, so Marylee is guilty.  This gives:
>
>  ---
>
>  Possible Solution 3:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine, Ruth, Elton
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy, Diego, Marylee
>
>  ---
>
>  Which is *also* consistent (though it does imply that Laine is a very friendly person!)
>
>  **Alternative: Ruth is guilty**
>
>  In this case, we have:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy, Ruth
>
>  [Diego and Elton in different groups]
>
>  At this point, for all remaining possibilities, there must be at least five guilty parties (Mika, Lamar, Mendy, Ruth, and Diego or Elton).  But remember our last clue: *"The solution with the fewest number of co-conspirators is likely to be the answer"*.  And we already have a solution with only four guilty people!  Thus, the solution with four guilty people must be the correct answer (assuming that Occam's razor works for detective work).  Done!
>
>  For completeness:
>
>  ---
>
>  Possible Solution 4:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine, Elton
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy, Ruth, Diego, Marylee
>
>  ---
>
>  Possible Solution 5:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine, Deigo, Marylee
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy, Ruth, Elton
>
>  ---
>
>  Possible Solution 6:
>
>  Innocent:
>  Roxann, Tracey, Laine, Deigo
>
>  Guilty:
>  Mika, Lamar, Mendy, Ruth, Elton, Marylee
>
>  ---

Comment: This is a fantastic solution!  Great effort.  Please feel free to leave comments about the puzzle too!

Comment: Mostly what I'm curious about is how useful this line is: "...but will also make a statement about a random other person about whom they know nothing. *If the person is their friend, they will say s/he is innocent.*"  I used it at the very beginning of my solution as the simplest way to resolve an assumption, but I think the puzzle is solvable without that knowledge.

Comment: So are you saying that it might be better if the boastful picked someone at random (friend or not) and make a random claim (innocent or guilty)

Comment: Oh no, I think it makes more sense for it to be the way that it is - I'm just claiming that I believe it to be extraneous information.

Comment: Okay, I get it. I'll try to remove extraneous information for my next one...

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for - if you want the puzzle to be harder, then yeah, I think there's a little more than the minimum required information here.  But harder isn't always better - the goal is being fun to solve!  As long as you manage that, you made a good puzzle.

Comment: So what did you think? I'm planning a third

Comment: Not bad - I enjoyed the opportunity to do a good mathematics-style proof, which I haven't really had since college - but I suspect that you'd get more answers/views/votes if you made it a bit simpler/shorter.  The general audience here seems a bit more on the casual side.